# Is it necessary to define logical Pauli in the centralizer of the stabilizer group

Tags: stabilizer-code

By **definition**, we define the logical Pauli operator as element of the centralizer of the stabilizer group $S$ in $G_n$ (the $n$-Pauli group).

It is a definition so why not.

My question is: mathematically speaking, is it really necessary ? Is this definition taken for mathematical simplicity (but we could imagine being less restrictive).

Indeed, what we need in the end is (i) to define a family of logical operator (ii) that verify the appropriate Pauli algebra.

Calling $U$ a logical operator, the minimal mathematical requirements we need are that it keeps any state $|\psi\rangle$ that is in the code space $C(S)$ inside of this code space. Thus, formally that:

$$\forall |\psi\rangle \in C(S): U |\psi\rangle \in C(S)$$

And this is all what we need conceptually. I guess that in the end we could find such operators $U$ not in the Pauli group that will respect the Pauli algebra. Are there hidden conditions I am not seing that would actually show that the logical Pauli operator **must** be elements of $G_n$ ?